# compiled inbook entry looks completely broken

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

my tex file is

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1.5in,right=1in,bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{times}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{MyBib}

\end{document}
```

and MyBib.bib is

```
@inbook{GL2022,
  author={Ggg, Iii and Lll, Yyy}, 
title={STD}, 
booktitle={FST}, 
publisher={CUP}, 
editor={Fff, Jjj and Kkk, Aaa and Sss, Ttt}, 
pages={123--456},
year={2345}, 
place={Cambridge}
}
```

If you compile the tex file, the resulting reference looks broken:

**GGG, Iii and Yyy Lll,** *STD,* CUP,

On the other hand, I expected

**GGG, Iii and Yyy Lll,** "STD," In: Fff, Jjj, Aaa KKK, and Ttt Sss, eds. *FST,* Cambridge: CUP: 2345:123--456

or sth like that. I'm not insisting on the exact format I wrote above, but I think it suffices to show I just want a sensible output from inputting all the information.

I'd greatly appreciate any and all advice on where I have gone wrong. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The `\bibliographystyle` determines what parts of the bibliography entry are used and how they're formatted.  If `aer` doesn't give you the result you want, you can look at others at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Natbib_bibliography_styles

Comment: Is there a way not to change the bibliographystyle aer, and just change what it shows for this particular entry?

Comment: How many other entries do you have?  How many `@inbook`?  What other types are you using?  Why are you using `aer` if you don't like how it's formatting your reference?

Comment: @Teepeemm - The OP was using an incorrrect entry type; it should be `@incollection` instead of `@inbook`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd greatly appreciate any and all advice on where I have gone wrong.

You're using the wrong entry type for the entry at hand. You should be using `@incollection`, *not* `@inbook`. And the name of the `place` field is wrong; it should be `address`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{MyBib.bib}
@incollection{GL2022,
  author   ={Ggg, Iii and Lll, Yyy}, 
  title    ={STD}, 
  booktitle={FST}, 
  publisher={CUP}, 
  editor   ={Fff, Jjj and Kkk, Aaa and Sss, Ttt}, 
  pages    ={123--456},
  year     ={2345},  
  address  ={Cambridge}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}

\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} %{times} 'times' is obsolete 
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{MyBib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm!!